# Voltage Noise Simulation with white noise variation issue

Tags: voltage, noise, source

I am trying to simulate the behaviour differential AOP, with its input common mode and differential mode filters, which is placed at the 2 outputs of the sensor, whose one  is noisy.

Of course, the average value of the output of the sensors can have differents values: for the example, 2.5V and then 5V, which i want to simulate with **the same noise**.

Here is the schematic:

[image]

- When I simulate with V3 = 2,5V, i got an rms noise value of **24mV** of Vsensor_output1_with_noise (*after removing dc value*)
- When I simulate with V3 = 5 V, i got an rms noise value of **20mV** of Vsensor_output1_with_noise (*after removing dc value*)

So I can't simulate the behaviour of that stage for different dc input values but with the same level of noise.
Do you have any idea to have a total independant noise source ?

*Note: i can't put a high voltage source resistance value because it would take part in the filters..*

Thank you,

Comment: For best details, also add `.opt plotwinsize=0` (disables waveform compression). You may also want to try the alternate solver (control panel > spice). Not lastly, `tripdv` and `tripdt` are tweaks for behavioural sources that can improve the dynamic range. Alternately, a current source (`bi`) with `Rpar=1` and `Cpar=` a very small value, pF or tens of pF, might also help (instead of `bv`). Maybe even reducing the timestep to be 1e-5 ~ 1e-6 of the total time, or even less (`.raw` files will get very large, `.save` command may come in handy).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
So you think it's a simulation configuration issue ?
I have tried to disable waveform compression to avoid any rounding leading to approximation. Nothing changed.
I have also tried alternate solver, and it changes the rms value for the 5V simulation from 20 to 18mV (but not the 2,5V simulation)..
I will try now current source and will work on tripdv and tripdt to know what it is.

Comment: Current source works pretty well to fix the level of the voltage noise measured on Vsensor_output1_with_noise net. 
But i don't still understand why it does not work with a direct noise voltage, any idea?
I did not find out tripdv and tripdt set up in the control pannel.

Comment: Current sources are preferred in LTspice due to superior convergence and the ability to add (small) capacitors across them (among other things), which smooth out the waveform around sharp transitions; these cause discontinuities in the derivative (`timestep too small` erros). `tripdv` and `tripdt` are parameters to add to the behavioural source, e.g. `I=white(time) tripdv=1 tripdt=1u`, which says anything less than 1 V / 1 us causes the solver to reduce its timestep to accurately (if possible) calculate the waveform.